# Downgrade Nexus 9 running lollipop to KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, downgrade, nexus-9

I'd like to downgrade my Nexus 9 to android 4.X (KitKat). Is this possible?
I'm not the pro doing something like that and I could not find something with google.

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unlikely, since the Nexus 9 was a Android 5.0 Lollipop launch device. There are no official (Google developed & distributed) versions of Android 4.4 KitKat for the Nexus 9.

Third party roms would be the way to go - but I have found no KitKat roms for the Nexus 9, and I personally doubt one would be developed unless there was a massive interest in it.

Comment: Agreed that the N9 is intended to be a Lollipop device, and you are unlikely to find a 3rd party ROM for that device.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it: http://thetechrism.com/downgrade-lollipop-kitkat-nexus/

You can't do it without doing some sort factory image/reset. Google has not officially distributed version of KitKat, however. So you'd have to use third party.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the easiest tutorial to downgrade your device here : [Downgrade Lollipop to KitKat](http://droidguru.org/downgrade-lollipop-to-kitkat-nexus/)

You have to wipe/ factory reset the device and flash the Factory Images to downgrade the Android version.